# tools\android.bat file doesn't execute in android studio

Tags: android, batch-file

I tried to execute SDK manager from android studio but I got an error message saying system cannot find the path specified.

```
7:38:44 AM ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\android sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\android sdk\tools\android.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can clearly see `sdk.exe, avd.exe` files in SDK folder as well as in `\android sdk\tools\lib` folder.

Also I can see android.bat file as `\sdk\tools\android.bat` but when i try to execute it says the path cannot be found.

I tried copy `android.bat` file to `\sdk\` but still its same. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hey give the guy a break, its really frustrating when you just want to learn and come up against issues like this

Hope this helps , it worked for me .

In your environment variables check the CommSpec variable value is set to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe.

It might be corrupted or something like C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; another-path

I had to resset my path to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe and my SDK mamanger worked